# LEFT JOIN with OR clause without UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, union

I know this shouldn't happen in a database, but it happened and we have to deal with it. We need to insert new rows into a table if they don't exist based on the values in another table. This is easy enough (just do LEFT JOIN and check for NULL values in 1st table). But...the join isn't very straight forward and we need to search 1st table on 2 conditions with an OR and not AND.  So basically if it finds a match on either of the 2 attributes, we consider that the corresponding row in 1st table exists and we don't have to insert a new one. If there are no matches on either of the 2 attributes, then we consider it as a new row. We can use OR condition in the LEFT JOIN statement but from what I understand, it does full table scan and the query takes a very long time to complete even though it yields the right results. We cannot use UNION either because it will not give us what we're looking for.
Just for simplicity purpose consider the scenario below (we need to insert data into tableA).

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableA') Is Not Null) Begin
    Drop Table #tableA End

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableB') Is Not Null) Begin
    Drop Table #tableB End

create table #tableA ( email nvarchar(50), id int )

create table #tableB ( email nvarchar(50), id int )


insert into #tableA (email, id) values ('123@abc.com', 1), ('456@abc.com', 2), ('789@abc.com', 3), ('012@abc.com', 4)

insert into #tableB (email, id) values ('234@abc.com', 1), ('456@abc.com', 2), ('567@abc.com', 3), ('012@abc.com', 4), ('345@abc.com', 5)

 --THIS QUERY IS CORRECTLY RETURNING 1 RECORD  
 select B.email, B.id  
 from #tableB B  
 left join #tableA A on A.email = B.email or B.id = A.id  
 where A.id is null

 --THIS QUERY IS INCORRECTLY RETURNING 3 RECORDS SINCE THERE ARE ALREADY RECORDS WITH ID's 1 & 3 in tableA though the email addresses of these records don't match  
select B.email, B.id  
from #tableB B  
left join #tableA A on A.email = B.email  
where A.id is null  
union 
select B.email, B.id  
from #tableB B  
left join #tableA A on B.id = A.id  
where A.id is null


If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableA') Is Not Null) Begin
    Drop Table #tableA End

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tableB') Is Not Null) Begin
    Drop Table #tableB End
```

The 1st query works correctly and only returns 1 record, but the table size is just few records and it completes under 1 sec. When the 2 tables have thousands or records, the query may take 10 min to complete. The 2nd query of course returns the records we don't want to insert because we consider them existing. Is there a way to optimize this query so it takes an acceptable time to complete?

Comment: Your query looks correct to me. I think you just need to look at adding proper indices if you aren't getting the performance you need.

Comment: "When the 2 tables have thousands or records, the query may take 10 min to complete." is this an assumption or did you check? Thousands of records isn't really that many, I wouldn't expect a query like that to perform that badly (especially if proper indexes are present). Maybe `EXISTS` gives better performance, but you really need to examine the execution plan

Comment: Yes, I tested it with OR in JOIN and it takes almost 10 min. Table A has over 50,000 records and table B has almost 20,000 records. If I remove OR from JOIN and JOIN on just 1 condition, it takes seconds. Unfortunately, we're dealing with SaaS DB and cannot create indices in it.

Comment: For my own reference, what service are you using that does not support indexing?

Comment: We use MS Dynamics 365.

Comment: I thought Dynamics was supposed to auto-create indices as needed. You might need to look at opening a support ticket. As others have said, this in not a lot of data, and not a complicated query. There is no reason for this to be slow.

Answer (score 1):

You are using an anti join, which is another way of writing the straight-forward `NOT EXISTS`:

```
where not exists 
(
  select null
  from #tableA A
  where A.email = B.email or B.id = A.id
)
```

I.e. where not exists a row in table A with the same email or the same id. In other words: where not exists a row with the same email and not exists a row with the same id.

```
where not exists (select null from #tableA A where A.email = B.email)
  and not exists (select null from #tableA A where B.id = A.id)
```

With the appropriate indexes

```
on #tableA (id);
on #tableA (email);
```

this should be very fast.

Comment: The performance with NOT EXISTS improved, so the query runs twice as fast as with OR in the JOIN statement. It took about 9 min before and now it takes about 4 min. I'd still like to cut the time down to under a minute. I realize that adding indexes would most likely do the trick, but like I mentioned before, we cannot create indexes since it's a SaaS solution.

Comment: @Tony the way you described the issue at hand, it sounds like a one off issue, so this fix would only have be be made once. With that in mind, is it really important to focus so much on the performance? Or is this a problem that needs to be fixed regularly?

Comment: @HoneyBadger This will continue to happen unfortunately. Performance is important, but it's not 'all be all' important. If we can get the execution time down to what we deem acceptable (under 2 min), it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tune something you can't see. Another option to get the data is to:

```
SELECT B.email
,      B.id 
FROM   #TableB B 

EXCEPT 

(
    SELECT B.email
    ,      B.id 
    FROM   #tableB B 
    INNER JOIN #tableA A 
          ON A.email = B.email
 
    UNION ALL

    SELECT B.email
    ,      B.id 
    FROM   #tableB B 
    INNER JOIN #tableA A 
          ON B.id = A.id
)
```

This way you don't have to use `OR`, you can use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT JOIN` and you can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` (though this advantage may well be negated by the `EXCEPT`). All of which *may* help your performance. Perhaps the joins can be more efficient when replaced with `EXISTS`.

You didn't mention how this problem occurred (where the data from both tables is coming from, and why they are out of sync when they shouldn't be), but it would be preferable to fix it at the source.

Comment: This is actually lightning fast. I never used EXCEPT before. I'll need to check if it works properly, but it completed in 12 sec compared to 4 min. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

No the query returns correctly 3 rows

because

```
 select B.email, B.id  
from #tableB B  
left join #tableA A on A.email = B.email  
where A.id is null
```

Allone reurns the 3 rows.

For your "problemm"

```
 select B.email, B.id  
 from #tableB B  
 left join #tableA A on A.email = B.email or B.id = A.id  
 where A.id is null
```

will che3kc for every row, if it is true to be included

So for example

```
('123@abc.com', 1)    ('234@abc.com', 1)
```

as the Ids are the same it will be joined

but when you join by the emails the condition is false and so is included in the result set

You can only use the UNION approach, when you are comparing only the emails or the ids, but with both the queries are not equivalent

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misworded my statement. It does correctly return 3 records. It's just not the result I'm looking for.

Comment: The query for the email chec doesn't make sense, as it will return always 3 rows i your example, and he id check alone will provide you wilth the wanted answer, so why do you use email at all

Comment: Because email + id combination is not necessarily unique. Consider adding following record to tableB and then run your query without email check: ('012@abc.com', 6). This record will be returned but I don't want it since I already have a record with the same email address in tableA.

Comment: yes, so the union gove you the right answer, no need for anything else.